# Hide icon-bar in mobile menu when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I'm trying to hide the icon-bar once we've clicked on it to display a sub-menu.

Right now, if I click on it, it's moving on right side but it should not display on this side.

**Code**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div id="mainmenutop" class="megamenu" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </a> 

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">          
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav megamenu megamenu-mobile-active-chk" style="background:#fff !important;">
            <li>
            <img style="width: 140px; margin: 5px 60px !important;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/Untitled-1.jpg'); ?>"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav megamenu megamenu-mobile-active-chk" style="margin:17px; border-bottom: 0px !important;margin-bottom:1px;">               
            <li style="color:#ffea00;">
                Welcome!
            </li>
            <li>
```

**Js**:

```
jQuery(document.body).on('dblclick', '#mainmenutop [data-toggle="dropdown"]' ,function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    jQuery(this).parent().show();
    if(!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open') && this.href && this.href != '#'){
        window.location.href = this.href;
    }

});
```

Comment: Can any one help me this

Comment: Add `jQuery('.icon-bar').hide();` to your click event.

Comment: @Pugazh I am not getting what your saying can you please change in my code.

Comment: Place the above code in your JS before the line `jQuery(this).parent().show();`

Comment: @Pugazh it is not working i have pasted an image above can you please check it if i click on menu button in mobile page it is showing like that in right side also it is displaying menu button it should not display

Comment: is there any one to help this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document.body).on('dblclick', '#mainmenutop [data-toggle="dropdown"]' ,function(event)
{
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    jQuery(this).parent().show();
    ('.icon-bar').hide();
    if(!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open') && this.href && this.href != '#'){
        window.location.href = this.href;
    }
});
```